# Hide specific part of text using CSS

Tags: css

Let's suppose I have the following text strings within a CSS class:

Text:

```
(2) 91-180
2, 91-180
```

Class:

```
<text class="nv-legend-text">(2) 91-180</text>
```

Is there, by any chance, a way how to hide the `(2)` or `2,` using CSS so only the text `91-180` is shown?

I have no other way how can I control/adjust the code itself, only custom CSS.

Comment: can't you just wrap `(2)` inside a span assign the said span with a class and give it a property of `display: none;`?

Comment: Without changing the HTML structure, there is no way for CSS to use logic and "find" or "grab" something and remove/hide it. CSS can only apply styles to elements that have a selector like `tag`, `class`, `id` etc.

Comment: I don't their is any way to make css see the text differently without changing html or adding some js. You CAN increase the text indent a bit more. But that wont work if the text to be hidden isn't at start or if it's longer/shorter then a specific number...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `text-indent` but you will need a specific value based on the font metrics:

```css
text {
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -18px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<text class="nv-legend-text">(2) 91-180</text>
```

Comment: yeah, with only custom css this looks like the best (if not only) option out there

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the text you want to hide and either use `display: none;` to make it disappear. Or `color: transparent;` to make the text transparent. See the snippet below for your reference:

```css
.ex1{
  display: none;
}
.ex2{
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="ex1">(2)</span>018231</p>
<p><span class="ex2">(2)</span>018231</p>
```

Comment: if they can wrap the text, why not simply removing it?
from the question: *only custom CSS.*

Comment: So they may manipulate it still with js if they want to? There's a difference with it not being in the DOM at all, and then just for it to be hidden temporarily, no?

Comment: that's not the question. I don't see any DOM manipulation requirement or JS involved in the question

Comment: I'm just answering your question of **why not simply removing it?**